# Gravar Data numa base de dados mysql usando o Java

Tags: java

Estou a criar uma aplicação que tem  uma base de dados  mysql contendo uma tabela de bancos e outra de movimentos bancários.

A tabela de movimentos bancários tem os seguintes atributos

Banco

Data de movimento

Descrição

Valor

O programa que cria os movimentos é o que vem mais abaixo, mas presiste um erro de sintaxe na instrução  "pstm.setDate(2, date);" (na zona do doPost da servlet)  .   O que está a falhar?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/CriarMovimentosBancos")
public class CriarMovimentosBancos extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            int banco=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println ("<html>");
            out.println ("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Criar Movimentos Banco</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<form method='POST'>");
            out.println("Banco:<br><input type='int' name='txtBanco' readonly='readonly' value='"+banco+"'>");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("Data:<br><input  type='date' name='txtData'>");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("Descrição:<br><input type='text' name='txtDescricao' ");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("Valor:<br><input type='number' placeholder='0.00' min='0' name='txtvalor'");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' value='Validar'>");
            out.println("</form>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
         }  catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter ();
        int banco  = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtBanco"));
            try {
        DateFormat formatter;
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date data = formatter.parse(request.getParameter("txtData"));
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        String descricao = request.getParameter("txtDescricao");
        Double valor = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("txtvalor"));
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            String SQL="Insert into mov__banco(banco,  data,  descricao, valor) Values(?,?,?,?)";
                    Connection  conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Contabilidade_Familiar", "root", "1234");
                    PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
                    pstm.setInt(1,banco);
                    pstm.setDate(2, date);
                    pstm.setString(3,descricao);
                    pstm.setDouble(4,valor);
                    pstm.execute();
                    pstm.close();
                    conn.close();
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/Contabilidade/MovimentosBanco?id="+banco);
                } catch (Exception e ) {
                    out.println("Erro - "+e.getMessage());
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
pstm.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

O [método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)) recebe um `java.sql.Date` como parametro e não `java.util.Date`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas infelizmente ainda não consegui que funcionasse. A referida data que vinha do "doGet" não está a ser reconhecida, apesar de eu a ter extraido com as instruções:            try {
        DateFormat formatter;
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date data = formatter.parse(request.getParameter("txtData"));
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }